# 2 count of Illegal Annotation Exception

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a Customer and CustomerFullAddress class and i am using JAXB to try to produce an XML file

```
<Customer CustomerID="GREAL">
    <CompanyName>Great Lakes Food Market</CompanyName>
    <ContactName>Howard Snyder</ContactName>
    <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle>
    <Phone>(503) 555-7555</Phone>
    <FullAddress>
        <Address>2732 Baker Blvd.</Address>
        <City>Eugene</City>
        <Region>OR</Region>
        <PostalCode>97403</PostalCode>
        <Country>USA</Country>
    </FullAddress>
</Customer>
```

The Customer Class looks like below (Its not a full implementation)

```
package org.abc.customers;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
@XmlType (propOrder = { "companyName", "contactName", "contactTitle", "phone" })

public class Customer {

*@XmlElement(name = "customerfulladdress")
private CustomerFullAddress custAdd;*

private String companyName;
private String contactName;
private String contactTitle;
private int phone;

public CustomerFullAddress getCustAddress() {
return custAdd;
}

public void setCustAddress(CustomerFullAddress custAdd) {
this.custAdd = custAdd;
}
...
```

While the CustomerFullAddress is

```
package org.abc.customers;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "customerfulladdress")
//If you want you can define the order in which the fields are written
//Optional
@XmlType(propOrder = { "address", "city", "region", "postalCode", "country" })

public class CustomerFullAddress {

private String address;
...

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
.....
 }
```

and the error is

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2
>   counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Property custAdd is present but
>   not specified in @XmlType.propOrder   this problem is related to the
>   following location:       at private
>   org.abc.customers.CustomerFullAddress
>   org.abc.customers.Customer.custAdd        at
>   org.abc.customers.Customer Property custAddress is present but not
>   specified in @XmlType.propOrder   this problem is related to the
>   following location:       at public
>   org.abc.customers.CustomerFullAddress
>   org.abc.customers.Customer.getCustAddress()       at
>   org.abc.customers.Customer

Thanks for having a look!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for [@XmlType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html):

> **propOrder**
>
> All of the JavaBean properties being mapped to XML Schema elements must be listed.

You need to add the `CustomerFullAddress` property to the `propOrder` for `Customer`.